# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'backend domain' from origin 'frontEnd domain' has been blocked by CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: python, .htaccess, cpanel, lets-encrypt, django-cors-headers

I am using o2switch server and I have created two different domain names, one for the back-end, and another for the front-end, my back-end created with Django rest framework, and my front-end -end was created with VueJs, my problem was when I use a VPN connection I get a cors policy error, I use LET'S ENCRYPT SSL CERTIFICATE for both domains, I configure the .htaccess file to allow my front end domain and I am also using Python's corsheaders library to authorize my domain name, but I still get the same error, some type of Internet connection is working fine but another Internet connection is getting a cors problem.
And when I put the back-end and the front-end in the same domain it works fine
settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'domainName',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
'domainName',
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
'domainName',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS=[
'domainName',]



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'application',
    'django_cleanup',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=204]
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Cache-Control, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size,If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name"
Header always add Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header always add Vary: Accept-Encoding
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't see how the type of connection could make any difference. (Unless your middleware was somehow configured to react differently, based on where requests come from?)

Comment: no, i just split backend and font-end on two different domain names, before that it was working fine, but when i split them, my client get cors error, so at this moment i try HOLA BROWSER , and I get the same error, it means chrome works fine but on HOLA with VPN not working

Comment: i am thinking to the ssl certificate if it can make this error because i am using free certificate let's encrypt

Comment: No, that can't be it. If the browser doesn't like the certificate, then the connection is aborted before client and server even start talking HTTP with each other. It would not even get to the point where it could check whether the response headers would allow the request or not.

Comment: _"i try HOLA BROWSER , and I get the same error, it means chrome works fine but on HOLA with VPN not working"_ - then you have a problem with a specific piece of software, rather than your own code/setup. We don't know what exactly that thing does, how its requests might differ from those a "normal" browser sends.

Comment: it's just a login form with POST method which contains data { "email": email, "password": password, isAuthenticated: true} and I get a response status code 204 OPTIONS remoteAddress IPADRESS and the cors-error was strict-origin-when-cross-origin this is when i add redirect in htaccess file but without redirect and with django cordsheaders i get status code error 307

Comment: `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` is not a CORS error, but a valid value for `Referrer-Policy`. _"but without redirect and with django cordsheaders i get status code error 307"_ - 307 is not an _error_ either, it is a redirection response code (307 Temporary Redirect.)

Comment: i will try the same code on localhost it works fine with chrome and hola,
on the server it is the error on the browser HOLA but on chrome works without problem
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.------.fr/api/logIn/' from origin 'https://test.-----------.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
really i don't know what is the problem

Comment: _"try the same code on localhost it works fine"_ - but do you even have a cross-origin setup in that case? Different hostname+port combinations for front- end backend?

Comment: yes: DEBUG = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://192.168.43.153:8080']
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://192.168.43.153:8080']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://192.168.43.153:8080']
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['http://192.168.43.153:8080', '192.168.43.153']
and in server i change this with the domain name

Comment: _"and in server i change this with the domain name"_ - just the domain names, or did you include the ports as well?

Comment: no just the domain name

Comment: Try and include the ports as well.

Comment: no unfortunately it does not work, I will try with .htaccess and remove all the controls from settings.py